# How to authenticate Socket.IO against PHP session id across domains

Tags: php, session, authentication, cookies, socket.io

I have a node/Socket.IO setup on node.mydomain.com, and a Apache/PHP stack on www.mydomain.com.

Presently I'm doing authentication with something like this:

1. **Client**: on connect, send a custom `authorization` event that includes
   PHPSESSID to the server
2. **Server**: on `authorization`, make a call to `api.php` using this cookie to get user information, send client this identity information
3. **Client**: can now perform actions using this identity

This is a bit kludgy since Socket.IO has a place for authentication ([On this wiki](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing)) which I would like to use. The problem is that I don't know how to send the PHPSESSID cookie information from the client to the server. They're on different domains, so the browser doesn't include them in the request.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend switching session handling and use Redis instead, which is also faster than the default file based session handling.

First install the [Redis server](http://redis.io/). After that you add [the phpredis extension](https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis) to PHP by first compiling it and then configuring your php.ini to use it.

```
extension=redis.so
session.save_handler = redis
session.save_path = "tcp://localhost:6379/"
```

From Node.js you can then read these sessions using the [node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) module.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing. But remember that you should always send the session id over https to the node instance!